# NSMutableDictionary inside JSONModel - EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, exc-bad-access, jsonmodel

Crashlytics reported this crash in one of my apps and I am not able to reproduce it at all, no matter what I do. 
This happens to about 5% of the users, so it's a pretty big deal.
I'm posting screenshots with the crash report and also the methods that are mentioned in the crash report. 
Any idea how to solve this?

[image: Crash Report]

This is where the app crashed:

```
#pragma mark - custom transformations
-(BOOL)__customSetValue:(id<NSObject>)value forProperty:(JSONModelClassProperty*)property
{
    if (!property.customSetters)
        property.customSetters = [NSMutableDictionary new];

    NSString *className = NSStringFromClass([JSONValueTransformer classByResolvingClusterClasses:[value class]]);

    if (!property.customSetters[className]) {
        //check for a custom property setter method
        NSString* ucfirstName = [property.name stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0,1)
                                                                       withString:[[property.name substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString]];
        NSString* selectorName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"set%@With%@:", ucfirstName, className];

        SEL customPropertySetter = NSSelectorFromString(selectorName);

        //check if there's a custom selector like this
        if (![self respondsToSelector: customPropertySetter]) {
            property.customSetters[className] = [NSNull null]; // this is line 855
            return NO;
        }

        //cache the custom setter selector
        property.customSetters[className] = selectorName;
    }

    if (property.customSetters[className] != [NSNull null]) {
        //call the custom setter
        //https://github.com/steipete
        SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(property.customSetters[className]);
        ((void (*) (id, SEL, id))objc_msgSend)(self, selector, value);
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

This is the originating method:

```
-(void)reloadUserInfoWithCompletion:(void (^) (LoginObject *response))handler andFailure:(void (^)(NSError *err))failureHandler {
    NSString *lat;
    NSString *lon;

    lat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.6f",[[LocationManager sharedInstance] getPosition].coordinate.latitude];
    lon = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.6f",[[LocationManager sharedInstance] getPosition].coordinate.longitude];

    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [params setObject:lat forKey:@"latitude"];
    [params setObject:lon forKey:@"longitude"];

    [[LoginHandler sharedInstance] getLoginToken:^(NSString *response) {

        NSDictionary *headers;
        if (response) {
            headers = @{@"Login-Token":response};
        }
        GETRequest *req = [GETRequest new];
        [req setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *response) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                NSLog(@"response: %@",response);
                NSError *err = nil;
                self.loginObject.userDetails = [[User alloc] initWithString:response error:&err]; // <- this is the line reported in the crash
                [self storeLoginObject];
                NSLog(@"%@",self.loginObject.userDetails);
//                [Utils updateFiltersFullAccessIfAll]; 
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    if (handler) {
                        handler(self.loginObject);
                    }
                });
            });
        }];
        [req setFailedHandler:^(NSError *err) {
            if (failureHandler) {
                failureHandler(err);
            }
        }];
        NSLog(@"%@",params);
        [req requestWithLinkString:USER_DETAILS parameters:nil andHeaders:headers];
    }];

}
```

Comment: Dont post screen shots of your code, copy/paste it. It's simpler for us, if we want to copy your code to show the error, we have to write it manually (no copy/paste), and it's also harder to read...

Comment: I posted the screenshots to outline the line numbers, but I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 2):

So `setObject:forKey:` can cause problems in two ways. 1. If `object` is `nil` or 2. the `key` is `nil`. Both could cause the crash you are seeing. Given that you are setting the `object` to `[NSNull null]` it is probably safe to assume that it is the `key` giving you problems (on line 855).

Walking back from there that would reveal that `className` is `nil`. If you look, your code does not protect against this. You make an assumption here that `NSStringFromClass` (a couple lines before) is giving you back a valid string, which assumes that the `value` originally passed into the method is non-`nil`. If it is `nil` it would make it past all of your checks, including `!property.customSetters[className]`, since this would be `!nil` allowing it to enter the `if`.

If I am reading your code right (a bit hard since I cannot test any of my assumptions) `NSLog(@"response: %@",response);` would print out a `nil` response.

Try seeing how your code handles these unexpected `nil`s and let me know in the comments how things go.

Comment: If the "response" object would be nil, JSONModel should be able to handle it. Look at the methods from the stack trace in JSONModel library ([here](https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel/blob/master/JSONModel/JSONModel/JSONModel.m)). I can't paste the code in the comments (too long)

Comment: even if I manually set "response" to nil, it doesn't even touch that piece of code that crashes.

Comment: @stonycis Thanks for your response. I'll take a look at it again (no time right now) and update my answer.

Comment: Can you check one thing for me. If `className` (at the beginning of the first method) is `nil` do you get a similar crash?

Comment: yeah, if I force `className` to be `nil`, that crash will occur (it was one of the first things I tested), but I can't create a scenario to reproduce it without manually setting it to `nil`.

Comment: if you go step by step through the methods inside JSONModel (the ones from the crash report) you'll see that `className` should never be `nil` (or am I missing something?)...

Comment: here's an idea... is there a chance that multiple concurrent calls (from different threads)  to `reloadUserInfoWithCompletion` method could produce that crash? (still not able to reproduce it)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use model custom setters you can replace JSONModel __customSetValue:forProperty: with swizzling or Aspects library

```
#import "JSONModel+Aspects.h"
#import "JSONModel.h"
#import "Aspects.h"

@implementation JSONModel (Aspects)

+(void)load {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        [JSONModel aspect_hookSelector:@selector(__customSetValue:forProperty:) withOptions:AspectPositionInstead usingBlock:^(id<AspectInfo> aspectInfo) {
            return NO;
        } error:NULL];
    });
}

@end
```